# why doesn't this $.post() work on iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, forms, submit

Why doesn't the following form work on iOS?

It works on Chrome / Android / Windows / Mac but not on Safari / Chrome on iOS.  I've narrowed down the issue to the jquery post function.

It makes it past the "e.preventDefault()" but never posts the data (I have a php script confirming the post never makes it to the server).  And the callback with the alert() does not fire.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="wl_form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="first">First Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="first" class="form-control" id="first">
</div>
<button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

form.addEventListener('submit', doSubmit);

function doSubmit (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    alert("ive made it this far");

    $.post("record.php",
    {
        first: $("#first").val()
    },
    function(data){
        console.log("submitting");
        alert("Success: " + data);
    });

    window.location.href = "nextpage.html";
}
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the window.location.href line?

Comment: gah! thats it.  i moved the href in to the callback and all is good now.  Thanks!  make that an answer ill mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are performing a redirect immediately after the post ajax call.  If you perform a page transfer fast enough, the ajax request will be cancelled and your backend may never see it.

As you found from the comments, moving the redirect into the success callback should allow you to perform the ajax request fully and then perform the redirect.

Comment: Every time I start one of these answers with "It looks like" I feel a little more like Clippy.